# Export GLM Coefficients of Correlation to csv in R

Tags: r, csv, correlation, glm

After running my GLM model in R, I run the summary command with `corr=TRUE` to get the coefficients of correlation for the various variables in my model.  What I would like to do is output those to a CSV file so I can open them in Excel.

I've tried using the `coef` command as well as several other methods I've found on this site for writing model output to a csv file.  So far, I haven't had any luck getting the coefficients of correlation, just the Estimate, Std. Error, t value and p value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `capture.output()`. Assume `model` is your GLM:

```
capture.output(summary(model, corr = TRUE), file = "filename.csv")
```

This takes the exact text of the summary and writes it to a file.

#### Update

To get just the correlation coefficients, you can access the `correlation` element of the `summary` object (only works when `corr = TRUE`):

```
df = data.frame(a = runif(100), b = runif(100))
model <- glm(a ~ b, data = df)

s <- summary(model, corr = TRUE)
s$correlation

#>             (Intercept)          b
#> (Intercept)   1.0000000 -0.8334063
#> b            -0.8334063  1.0000000
```

You can take this output and write it to a csv which should preserve the table-like structure:

```
write.csv(s$correlation, file = "filename.csv")
```

[Here is the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/summary.glm.html) for `summary.glm` which shows the different members of the list that can be extracted.

> `correlation`
>   (only if `correlation` is `true`.) The estimated correlations of the estimated coefficients.

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Thanks, this does work, but is there any way to make it "prettier" so that the columns line up with their headings?

Comment: @JT. I've added how to get just the correlation coefficients like you asked and how to export to a csv and maintain the formatting